# Does pdb have a "comm" command like gdb?

Tags: python, pdb

In GDB, users can define some actions that run automatically when a breakpoint is hit. For example,

```
 b foo.cpp:100
 comm 1
 p x
 end
```

Does pdb have the similar function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html, you can find:

```
commands [bpnumber]
  Specify a list of commands for breakpoint number bpnumber. The commands themselves appear on the following lines. Type a line containing just ‘end’ to terminate the commands
```